# Why does one of the segments appear disabled on segmented control?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control with custom images for segments.  I have created it as follows

```
[repaymetSegmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"-SingleJointOffState"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[repaymetSegmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"-SingleJointOnState"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


[repaymetSegmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on_div"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[repaymetSegmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off_div"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

CGRect frameSeg= repaymetSegmentedControl.frame;
[repaymetSegmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(frameSeg.origin.x, frameSeg.origin.y-5, frameSeg.size.width, frameSeg.size.height + 15)];
```

Here when I run the app I am selecting one of the segments based on preferences.  It appears as shown in image.  Not sure what's wrong with it.

[image]

The images being used are as follows

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: no one has an answer to this ?

Comment: What is the issue? Can you post your expected outcome?

Comment: How many segments do you have? 3? Is the problem that the first one shows up blank?

Comment: @Rivera as you can see there are three buttons but first one appears to be blank actually its not blank the text appears in white unlike the second button, if i click on first button then it appears fine, or if the selected button is first button then also it appears to be fine but if the selected button in the beginning is something else than first then it appears like this, shown in figure with white text.

Comment: @JackWu please check my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code in `viewDidLoad` gave me the result that I think you are looking for (I renamed your images to make things a bit clearer for me).

```
    [repaymetSegmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteBG"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [repaymetSegmentedControll setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinkBG"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [repaymetSegmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinkBG"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [repaymetSegmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    [repaymetSegmentedControll setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateHighlighted ];
    [repaymetSegmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected ];

    [repaymetSegmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinkDivider"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [repaymetSegmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinkDivider"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [repaymetSegmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinkDivider"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateHighlighted rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [repaymetSegmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinkDivider"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [repaymetSegmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteDivider"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Using this code, the result is like this . Attached Image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: what happens if the second segment is selected on launch by default ? Thats the case I am interested in and it doesn't work

Comment: ok just tested and it worked actually what was missing in my code was the test attributes after setting which it gave me correct output. thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the text color for selected segments is set to black and white for the other. So in your screenshot the middle segment is selected.

The problem could be somewhere else:

```
[repaymetSegmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"-SingleJointOffState"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[repaymetSegmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"-SingleJointOnState"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It seems weird to have image names starting with `-`.

```
[repaymetSegmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on_div"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[repaymetSegmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off_div"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You seem to be missing right selected/left normal option.

Also as your design seems pretty flat, I'm not sure you need any of those.

Finally could you attach all the images to the question?

Comment: attached are the images

Comment: are the images for right selected / left normal etc needed ?

Comment: This works for segment control having two segments ! also i tried setting all three dividers still result it same

Comment: I think this is a bug in iOS7, I created a simple project with same kind of segmented control , it has same issue, with images in background , when i set the selected segment as 0 then there is no issue but if the selected segment is anything other than 0 it shows up like above on more than two segmented control.

Answer (score 0):

Your segment divider image should be the same height as the background images.